# I need help with combining Voronoi texture and Noise Texture

Tags: shaders, procedural, conversion

I have this colored noise map

[image]

I think I need to combine this Noise map and Voronoi Texture to get something like this

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as if you need to sample your noise at the feature-points ('Position') of the *Voronoi* texture..

[image]

(Put whatever texture/cluster you are using, in place of of the *Magic*, above)

Comment: Thanks Robin for the Answer. But I want the noise itself because I am making a random procedural texture. But I found a way to satisfy my need. I joined Voronoi's Position to the vector of the Noise Texture which gave me the result which I was looking for...But, This idea is actually inspired by you only, Thank you once again....My regards.

Comment: Hehe.. language crossover.. that's what I meant. Have rephrased. :)